# Fast algorithm for Graph Edit Distance to vertex-labeled Path Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, edit-distance

Let $G$ be a vertex-labeled directed graph with unique labels $L$. Let $G_P$ be a [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) with the same vertex labels and the same number of vertices as $G$.

I know that in the general case computing the [Graph Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance) is NP-hard (if approximations are excluded) and APX-hard to approximate.

I'm interested in a subset of the problem:

**Is there a general algorithm for quickly computing the Graph Edit Distance from any $G$ to any $G_P$, restricted to only adding and removing edges?**

Let, for example, $G=(\{a,b,c\}, \{(a,b), (b,c), (c,a)\})$:

[image]

Then the graph edit distance, excluding vertex addition/deletion, to the path directed graph $G_P=(\{a,b,c\}, \{(a,b), (b,c)\})$ is 1.

It feels to me like this is a case that's restricted enough that there should be an efficient algorithm for computing the distance, but I might be mistaken.

Furthermore, for a given directed vertex-labeled graph, **is there a known algorithm for finding the set of labeled path graphs with the minimal graph-edit distance to the original graph?**

So far, for both questions, I haven't been able to find an answer (google scholar gives only semi-related answers to ["graph edit distance to linear graph"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=graph+edit+distance+to+linear+graph&btnG=) and ["graph edit distance to path graph"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=graph+edit+distance+to+path+graph&btnG=).

[Context for why I'm asking the question](https://niplav.github.io/turning.html), probably not relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both graphs have the same unique labels, there is a unique minimal way to edit edges: remove edges missing in the target, and add edges missing in the source. This problem is solvable in a linear time.

For finding the minimal-distance path graph (permutation), this is equivalent to the 0-1 TSP (the traveling salesman problem with edge cost 0 or 1):

The edit cost can be expressed as $|E| + |P| - 2 |E \cap P|$ where $(V, E)$ is the source graph and $P$ is the target path.
By setting cost $0$ on edges and cost $1$ to non-edges, the cost of a tour is equal to the edit cost of the path plus some constant.

0-1 TSP is NP-hard but solvable in $O(2^n n^2)$ time by dynamic programming.